# How to connect Visual Studio to Team Foundation Server Team Project from C# code

Tags: c#, tfs

Is it possible to connect Visual Studio to TFS Team Project from code? I found article how to connect to TFS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb286958.aspx however this allows me to perform basic actions on TFS from code but not connecting Visual Studio.
[image: sample]

Comment: Do you know that once a solution is checked into TFS, that opening the solution again will connect to TFS?

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I wanna connect to TFS to explore sources at first, not opening particular solution.

Comment: Still not sure what you're looking for. Doesn't the Source Control Explorer do what you want?

Comment: It does, but the question is 'How to connect Visual Studio to Team Foundation Server Team Project FROM C# CODE', not using the explorer

Comment: Yeah, but are you asking how to do it from C# code _inside of Visual Studio_? I'm not sure what your scenario is. Is this something you want do inside of VS? Once it's done, you'll use VS (Source Control Explorer) to explore the sources?

Comment: I have to change the connection to TFS frequently and don't like the clicking too much, just create simple switch button in VS.

Comment: You should really update your question with more of your requirement. Clearly, not many people have the same requirements you do.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you can't... you have 3 options:

1-Making an extension for VS Team Explore and this extension will depend on you are already connected using VS.

[Extending Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/12/21/extending-team-explorer-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx)

2- Making a separate exe so you will use the the **TeamProjectPicker** so
    you can choose which TFS and which Team Project you want to connect to.

```
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
    using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server;
    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles(); // Makes it look nicer from a console app.
                //"using" pattern is recommended as the picker needs to be disposed of
                using (TeamProjectPicker tpp = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.MultiProject, false))
                {
                    DialogResult result = tpp.ShowDialog();
                    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Selected Team Project Collection Uri: " + tpp.SelectedTeamProjectCollection.Uri);
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Selected Projects:");
                        foreach (ProjectInfo projectInfo in tpp.SelectedProjects)
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine(projectInfo.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

3- Use API for TFS and hardcode path or put it in a config file like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;

namespace TfsApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            // Connect to Team Foundation Server
            //     Server is the name of the server that is running the application tier for Team Foundation.
            //     Port is the port that Team Foundation uses. The default port is 8080.
            //     VDir is the virtual path to the Team Foundation application. The default path is tfs.
            Uri tfsUri = (args.Length < 1) ?
                new Uri("http://Server:Port/VDir") : new Uri(args[0]);

            TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer =
                TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(tfsUri);

            // Get the catalog of team project collections
            ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> collectionNodes = configurationServer.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(
                new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection },
                false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

            // List the team project collections
            foreach (CatalogNode collectionNode in collectionNodes)
            {
                // Use the InstanceId property to get the team project collection
                Guid collectionId = new Guid(collectionNode.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]);
                TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionId);

                // Print the name of the team project collection
                Console.WriteLine("Collection: " + teamProjectCollection.Name);

                // Get a catalog of team projects for the collection
                ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> projectNodes = collectionNode.QueryChildren(
                    new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.TeamProject },
                    false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

                // List the team projects in the collection
                foreach (CatalogNode projectNode in projectNodes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Team Project: " + projectNode.Resource.DisplayName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find step by step guide to Connect Visual Studio to TFS

http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/code/connect-vs/